# The looping tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I don't think the [looping](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/looping) tag should be called that. I think one of two things should happen:

1. It should be renamed to [loops](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/loops) which fits with, for example, Stack Overflow, and just seems more professional.
2. It should be removed, and in its place should be tags like [while-loops](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/while-loops), [for-loops](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/for-loops), etc.

Option 1? Option 2? Keep it as it is? Other ideas?

Comment: I think you are comparing apples to oranges. It should be named [tag:fruitloops]

Answer (score 2):

Vote for this answer if you agree that [looping](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/looping) should be renamed to [loops](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/loops) which fits with, for example, Stack Overflow, and just seems more professional.

- From a teaching perspective the concept of looping is sufficiently complex to warrant it's own tag, [loops](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/loops) to remain consistent with other related sites seems worth the effort. Splitting the tag into its variations, however, seems a little excessive. For pedagogical use, all the loops are sufficiently similar as to admit one tag.
- Ignoring the idea of if it should be renamed or not, I think that the loop type tags will all arrive in their own time if they're needed. Currently, they're not needed and so don't exist.

---

> This answer is marked community wiki so that reasons can be edited in.

Answer (score 0):

Vote for this answer if you agree that [looping](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/looping) should be removed, and in its place should be tags like [while-loops](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/while-loops), [for-loops](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/for-loops), etc.

---

> This answer is marked community wiki so that reasons can be edited in.

Answer (score -2):

Vote for this answer if think that the tagging shouldn't be changed.

---

> This answer is marked community wiki so that reasons can be edited in.